# Ubuntu(20.04.3) blank screen after game crash

Tags: crash

i was playing games in full screen but after hitting alt-tab, it crashed my screen and now doesnt show anything, even after restarting. It only works in recovery mode or with nomodeset but only goes low res. My screen goes blank after the grub menu.

specs: AMD ATI Radeon HD 4350/455,  Intel Core 2 Quad Q8300, 4g RAM

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? Do you know which driver you were using for the graphics card? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1372640/edit)

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64 and idk much about graphics driver sorry this is my first time i posted an question